# Redirect requests to / that come from /subdirectory to go to /subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following folder structure:

```
/
    index.html
    /sub
        index.html
        dist/...
```

When visiting the url `/sub` there are some resources in `/sub/dist` that are being requested from `/dist` instead of `/sub/dist`. Obviously this results in a 404.

I need to rewrite ONLY those requests that come from under `/sub` to actually go to `/sub`, rather than from the root url.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

First, I check if the referrer came from my subdirectory:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} /sub
```

Then, I check if it has `/sub` in it's URI:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/driving/
```

Finally, I add in `/sub` to the url:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Anything trying to use the referrer should not be considered a “solution”, unless you are in full control of the enviroment (and can therefor _force_ all browsers used to send one.)